# How to find a deleted question?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

[HTML5 Canvas Performance and Optimization Tips, Tricks and Coding Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8205828/996493)

The above question is deleted but answers on many other questions link me to this question. It must have been a good question because many people are linking to it. How do I find this deleted question?

Comment: @Raynold Is their anyway in which I could have a look at the question and answers?

Comment: as you have pasted the link here, let moderator decide whether to leave that question deleted or it may be undelete if it is that much useful for others.

Comment: It wasn't really a question at all, but a long list of little tips on how to use Canvas. Doesn't fit in SO's Q&A format, but perhaps in the posters blog.

Comment: @BoPersson yes agree with you.

Comment: The only valid solution is to remove the links to the question.

Comment: @BЈовић right, couldn't find any permanent free host. Any ideas?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd is that a reply to a deleted comment?

Comment: [Sauce of the thread](http://pastebin.com/HD7T32k7)

Comment: @Stijn yes, I copied the whole contents into a Word document and hosted it somewhere then after a while it was deleted so BЈовић alerted me and that was my reply.

Answer (score -2):

Well, the way to <strike>find</strike> get the contents of a deleted question is to a) have a link (which you do) and b) ask a 10K user, hopefully with a good reason. (which I think you do).

Sorry I can't help personally.

Comment: Are you and Raynold share minds? :)

Comment: How a 10k user find deleted question ? I mean I have 10k on so but unable to find deleted question without link