# Timeline is encoding my quote!

Tags: bug, status-completed, timeline, html-entities

Stumbled upon [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/171822/timeline):

> [image]

[Link to original comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171822/how-to-find-a-deleted-question#comment652167_171822).

Maybe another victim of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197349/152859), unseen until now?

Comment: It is part of our cunning plan to find out **who** is actually using that rout.

Comment: @Oded I can&#39;t believe this!

Comment: I *really* don&#39;t think this is a big deal at all. I mean, c&#39;mon, it&#39;s not like people use those things much!

Comment: @Andrew &lt;no big deal&gt;!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I think you mean &lt;nobigdeal /&gt; ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's been fixed and will be deployed in the next build.

What's wrong with repeated encoding? Looks great on my machine!

What's wrong with repeated encoding? Looks great on my machine!

What&#39;s wrong with repeated encoding? Looks great on my machine!

&#87;&#104;&#97;&#116;&#38;&#97;&#109;&#112;&#59;&#35;&#51;&#57;&#59;&#115;&#32;&#119;&#114;&#111;&#110;&#103;&#32;&#119;&#105;&#116;&#104;&#32;&#114;&#101;&#112;&#101;&#97;&#116;&#101;&#100;&#32;&#101;&#110;&#99;&#111;&#100;&#105;&#110;&#103;&#63;&#32;&#76;&#111;&#111;&#107;&#115;&#32;&#103;&#114;&#101;&#97;&#116;&#32;&#111;&#110;&#32;&#109;&#121;&#32;&#109;&#97;&#99;&#104;&#105;&#110;&#101;&#33;

`&#38;&#35;&#56;&#55;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#48;&#52;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#57;&#55;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#49;&#54;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#51;&#56;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#57;&#55;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#48;&#57;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#49;&#50;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#53;&#57;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#51;&#53;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#53;&#49;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#53;&#55;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#53;&#57;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#49;&#53;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#51;&#50;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#49;&#57;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#49;&#52;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#49;&#49;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#49;&#48;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#48;&#51;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#51;&#50;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#49;&#57;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#48;&#53;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#49;&#54;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#48;&#52;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#51;&#50;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#49;&#52;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#48;&#49;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#49;&#50;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#48;&#49;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#57;&#55;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#49;&#54;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#48;&#49;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#48;&#48;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#51;&#50;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#48;&#49;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#49;&#48;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#57;&#57;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#49;&#49;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#48;&#48;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#48;&#53;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#49;&#48;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#48;&#51;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#54;&#51;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#51;&#50;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#55;&#54;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#49;&#49;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#49;&#49;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#48;&#55;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#49;&#53;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#51;&#50;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#48;&#51;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#49;&#52;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#48;&#49;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#57;&#55;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#49;&#54;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#51;&#50;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#49;&#49;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#49;&#48;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#51;&#50;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#48;&#57;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#50;&#49;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#51;&#50;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#48;&#57;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#57;&#55;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#57;&#57;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#48;&#52;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#48;&#53;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#49;&#48;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#49;&#48;&#49;&#59;&#38;&#35;&#51;&#51;&#59;`

Comment: This one goes straight to my favorites! ;)

Comment: FWIW, this also happens for moderators viewing the flags on a post. The tooltip over a "declined" at the right will have the quotes encoded. In case you want to take a look at that. ;)